# What steps need to be taken for my non-EU spouse (Lebanese) to move with me to the UK (I am a British Citizen). Details below

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, non-residents

Here are the facts:

1. I am a British Citizen
2. My wife is Lebanese - she has a 5 year residency permit in Germany.
3. We have been living in Germany since 2016
4. She has been working and paying taxes etc since 2016 in Germany.

Our Plan: We want to make the move to the UK(London)this year and we would like to know what steps we need to go through in order to make this happen. Can we apply from Germany to speed up the whole process or is it better to do so once in London? Which visa or application do we need to apply for? At what point can my wife begin working in the UK? Also we are mindful of Brexit but are not sure how this will affect us?

p.s. if anyone has an immigration lawyer contact. Much appreciated.

thanks in Advance

Comment: Does your wife have an Article 10 residence card (that is, does her German residence permit say that she is the family member of a union citizen)?

Comment: @Iman You do not need to prove any cohabitation if you are married.

Comment: @MJeffryes My visa solicitor (a big MNC co.) just asked me for cohabitation evidences eventhoigh we are legally married! I have seen a similar case in Canda whos sponsorship request has been rejected while they were legally married in Toronto! Your argument is solid and seems reasonable, but that was what happened to me.

Comment: @phoog yes it does - Eu family member residency permit.

Comment: @MJeffryes is this solicitor in the UK? Can you give me their details please? Also any idea whether I need to be in the UK when applying? or can we do it now while in Berlin? simply by going through the steps on the gov website?

Comment: @Iman Your initial comment "if you can show 2 years of co-habitation" is wrong though. You do not *need* to show this. Evidence of cohabitation could be used to prove a genuine relationship, but there is no strict requirement as there is for an unmarried partner visa. Many couples apply successfully with no cohabitation.

Comment: @MJeffryes Deep down inside I completely agree with you. When someone is legally married, then it’s done! There should be no further documents or evidence required. But my lawyers things differently.

Comment: @Iman Yes, I understand, but this kind of evidence is not necessary or available to all couples. When you say something like "If you are able to show 2 years of co-habitation...", it can mislead because it implies that if this evidence is not available, then you cannot apply for the visa, which is wrong.

Comment: @MJeffryes Ok, since you are insisting, I am going to delete the comment 